# Python Element Tree xml parser: how can I iterate the children nodes to alter the attribute?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, elementtree

I was given an XML file and was asked to change the fill color. I've been trying out Element Tree and every time I tried accessing the nodes, I kept getting a syntax error. I've copied the XML file I need to parse below and then what I need to change in the code below that:

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="300px"
 height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Shapes">
<g id="RootTip">
    <path fill="none" d="M98.178,143.456l112.03-0.079l-5.458,56.235c0,0-1.472,7.203-2.704,7.552s1.086,1.377,1.086,1.377
        l-2.537,12.993l1.751,0.441l-5.252,13.787c0,0,0,6.126,0.219,7.658S196,244.079,196,244.079s-6.784,13.565-8.097,14.879
        s-9.846,8.752-11.597,9.628s-10.941,4.158-10.941,4.158l0.209,1.312L159,273.619V275c0,0-13.547,1.683-17.486-0.943
        s-12.035-7.439-14.879-10.284s-10.722-13.13-12.254-17.287s-7.44-18.38-7.002-20.568s1.094-3.501,1.094-3.501l-3.282-12.254
        l-3.72-32.386l-0.875-5.688l-0.875-9.409L98.178,143.456z"/>
    </g>
</g>
```

I need to change the path fill to any color such as "blue" or "red".

I used the tutorial online and tried doing this as my first step:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
    print child.tag, child.attrib
```

However, I kept getting this syntax message??!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 2, in <fragment>
Syntax Error: print child.tag, child.attrib: <string>, line 2, pos 15
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this problem? I'm new to programming so any feedback would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: it is complaining about line 2, position 15, which is the filename **country_data.xml**

Comment: but I had no problems with line 2 until I tried using the for loop..

Comment: the loop was when you began using the content of the file, see my answer below

Comment: The `</svg>` end tag is missing in the XML. But with that fixed, I am unable to reproduce the error in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your XML file and I had a problem that it is not valid XML.
`<svg>` miss `</svg>` element or just `<svg ... />`

It makes different error message, but I can't see anything wrong with your code, which also works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your 'XML' file.

I presume you were looking at [this tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)  -  see how this XML file looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
 <country name="Liechtenstein">
    <rank>1</rank>
    <year>2008</year>
    <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
    <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
 </country>
 <country name="Singapore">
    <rank>4</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
 </country>
 <country name="Panama">
    <rank>68</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
    <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
 </country>
</data>
```

The first line in the file declares the type, stating which XML version it is `<?xml version="1.0"?>`

Your file begins by stating it is an SVG graphics file:

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "
```

Compare it with [this example](http://redsymbol.net/articles/svg-markup-chomsky/) and you can see the `<?xml version` line must come first.

Since you are just starting out it might be best to complete the tutorial you are using with the data provided, then once it works adapt it to your file.

Comment: *and you can see the `<?xml version` line must come first.* If present in an XML document, it must come first. But it can be left out. It is not mandatory. It is not clear how to reproduce the error in the question, but it is not caused by a missing XML declaration.

Comment: I have tried the tutorial again and I got the same syntax error at line 1, position 1. The "<?xml version" line is present so I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong. I am using Wing to parse the document. Is it better to use sublime text?

Comment: @SophieSu: Please ensure that the question includes everything needed to reproduce the problem. People seem to be unable to do just that, so something is missing. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.